# GIT diff does not show any difference

Tags: git

I'm using GIT and when I issue - git status, I get a list of files..

Im trying to find the difference for one of the file using

```
git diff file1.py
```

but just get the following,

```
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

Why doesn't it show any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because only file mode has changed and nothing else.